# Sqlite query to determine gender by first name

Tags: syntax, sqlite

I have 2 sqlite3 tables :
**FND** is a Table of names and their likely gender i.e.:

```
nm,gndr  <-column names
Aliyah,F
Moses,M
Peter,M
```

**Members** is second table i.e.

```
Fname,Lname    <-column names
DAVID X, BAKER
MARY MIA,MCGEE
TINA HEATHER,JOHNSON
JIM PETER TOM, SANTINO
```

The members table has first and middle names in the fname column.

I am trying to write a query to list the Members table fnames column, with a generated column indicating gender based on the first word in the fname column.

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
select m.fname,(select gndr from FND where upper(nm) like m.fname||'%')as gender
from Members m
```

can anyone correct my sql statement?

Answer (score 0):

```
... upper(nm) like m.fname||'%'
```

Let's look at some example values:

```
nm:    'David'
fname: 'DAVID X'

SQL: 'DAVID' LIKE 'DAVID X%'
```

This obviously does not match.

You have to reverse the LIKE operands:

```
m.fname LIKE nm||'%'
```